# Extending visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vsx, extensibility

I want to write an AddIn for visual studio (2010). My goal is to add a menuitem to the context menu of all .cs files in the solution explorer. Or maybe just to context menu of the code window, although I prefer the first thing. I've been browsing around on the [Visual Studio Extensibility website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/bb980955.aspx) but I must admit that I'm having a hard time finding a tutorial on how to achieve what I want to. I guess that I don't really understand the VS extensibility model to be honest.

So I thought that some of the smart people here must have tried it before, and I'm hoping to save some time by asking here instead of fumbling in the dark.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a blog post on something pretty similar at http://www.runeibsen.dk/?p=237. Unfortunately, it is for VS2008 and AFAIK VS2010 is all WPF based now, in which case you may not be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [codeproject Article-- LineCounterAddin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/LineCounterAddin.aspx), its a good one. Explaining the VS IDE internals needed to code Addins.

And quick googling shows this one [Add-In That Converts C# Code To Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163652.aspx)